# How to emit html video data via socket.io?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

What I am trying to do is emitting data coming from

```
// this returns data coming from webcam and microphone
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      });
```

this code returns a `MediaStream` obj which I link to my **video** element like this

```
video.srcObject = stream
```

now I wanna emit this data via socket io, I have done my research and I could only emit the video frames with no audio and I take the data I emitted into **img**

`originalCanvas` is a **canvas** I am streaming my video in

```
socket.emit("video-data",OriginalCanvas.toDataURL("image/webm"));
```

so this part emits the video frames only and I wanna emit audio as well to receive the data in **video** tag.

Comment: Hey man, if the idea here is video chat why not use WebRTC?

Comment: didn't know that was thing, will look into it but i think it's possible to do the same thing with socket.io

Comment: It's not quite the same actually, WebRTC is a way to peer to peer connection you can check this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/